# MySQL: retrieving the last record from each group and combining with the data of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a purchase table that information regarding the products bought. This will generate one one or more rows in the `tStockMP` table for each individual product bought.

Now, I need to display the table information for each product in stock. Since the purchase table contains the history of the changes, that information is in the highest `keyid` when grouped by `purchase_id` in the `tPurchases` table.

I've provided a complete script, here with example data describing my problem.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tPurchases;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tStockMP;

-- The purchase table
CREATE TABLE tPurchases (
                            keyid                        INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            brand                        VARCHAR(255),
                            model                        VARCHAR(255),
                            purchase_id                  INT
                           );
                           
INSERT INTO tPurchases (brand,model,purchase_id) VALUES ("Hp","note1",23);
INSERT INTO tPurchases (brand,model,purchase_id) VALUES ("Lg","IPSLED",45);
INSERT INTO tPurchases (brand,model,purchase_id) VALUES ("Hp","notE1",23);
INSERT INTO tPurchases (brand,model,purchase_id) VALUES ("Bx","BOX",56);
INSERT INTO tPurchases (brand,model,purchase_id) VALUES ("LG","IPSLED",45);
INSERT INTO tPurchases (brand,model,purchase_id) VALUES ("HP","NOTE1",23);

                           
-- The Stock MP Table
CREATE TABLE tStockMP (
                       keyid                        INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                       purchase_id                  INT,
                       status                       TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO tStockMP (purchase_id,status) VALUES (23,1);
INSERT INTO tStockMP (purchase_id,status) VALUES (23,1);
INSERT INTO tStockMP (purchase_id,status) VALUES (23,0);
INSERT INTO tStockMP (purchase_id,status) VALUES (45,0);
INSERT INTO tStockMP (purchase_id,status) VALUES (56,1);
INSERT INTO tStockMP (purchase_id,status) VALUES (56,1);
INSERT INTO tStockMP (purchase_id,status) VALUES (56,0);

-- Example data
-- 
-- tPurchases table
-- keyid brand model   purchase_id
-- 0     Hp    note1   23
-- 1     Lg    IPSLED  45
-- 2     Hp    notE1   23
-- 3     Bx    BOX     56
-- 4     LG    IPSLED  45
-- 5     HP    NOTE1   23
-- 
-- 
-- tStockMP   table.
-- purchase_id  status
-- 23           1 
-- 23           1
-- 23           0
-- 45           0
-- 56           1
-- 56           1
-- 56           0
-- 
-- 
-- Expected result
-- 
-- purchase_id  status  brand  model  
-- 23           1       HP     NOTE1   
-- 23           1       HP     NOTE1
-- 23           0       HP     NOTE1
-- 45           0       LG     IPSLED
-- 56           1       Bx     BOX
-- 56           1       Bx     BOX
-- 56           0       Bx     BOX


SELECT s.keyid, s.purchase_id, s.status, p.brand, p.model, p.keyid AS purkeyid 
FROM tStockMP AS s, tPurchases AS p 
WHERE s.purchase_id = p.purchase_id;

-- +-------+-------------+--------+-------+--------+----------+
-- | keyid | purchase_id | status | brand | model  | purkeyid |
-- +-------+-------------+--------+-------+--------+----------+
-- |     1 |          23 |      1 | Hp    | note1  |        1 |
-- |     1 |          23 |      1 | Hp    | notE1  |        3 |
-- |     1 |          23 |      1 | HP    | NOTE1  |        6 |-> *
-- |     2 |          23 |      1 | Hp    | note1  |        1 |
-- |     2 |          23 |      1 | Hp    | notE1  |        3 |
-- |     2 |          23 |      1 | HP    | NOTE1  |        6 |-> *
-- |     3 |          23 |      0 | Hp    | note1  |        1 |
-- |     3 |          23 |      0 | Hp    | notE1  |        3 |
-- |     3 |          23 |      0 | HP    | NOTE1  |        6 |-> *
-- |     4 |          45 |      0 | Lg    | IPSLED |        2 |
-- |     4 |          45 |      0 | LG    | IPSLED |        5 |-> *
-- |     5 |          56 |      1 | Bx    | BOX    |        4 |-> *
-- |     6 |          56 |      1 | Bx    | BOX    |        4 |-> *
-- |     7 |          56 |      0 | Bx    | BOX    |        4 |-> *
-- +-------+-------------+--------+-------+--------+----------+
```

The I would need to "filter" the results so that ONLY the * rows remain in the final query, lest I need to do it by hand. But I don't know how to modify my query and make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  I typical solution is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.keyid, s.purchase_id, s.status, p.brand, p.model, p.keyid AS purkeyid 
FROM tStockMP s JOIN
     tPurchases p 
     ON s.purchase_id = p.purchase_id
WHERE p.keyid = (SELECT MAX(p2.keyid)
                 FROM tPurchases p2
                 WHERE p2.purchase_id = p.purchase_id
                );
```

With an index on `tPurchases(purchase_id, keyid)`, this often has the best performance.

If I approached this with window functions, I would phrase it as:

```
SELECT s.keyid, s.purchase_id, s.status, p.brand, p.model, p.keyid AS purkeyid 
FROM tStockMP s JOIN
     (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_id ORDER BY keyid DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tPurchases p 
     ) p
     ON s.purchase_id = p.purchase_id
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

GMB has an alternative approach.  If you have lots of data, it would be interesting to compare the performance of the two methods.  I would advise the same index as above for all comparisons.

Comment: I'm interested on why no using , in the from clause? I use them all the time. But I'm very new to writing queries so, I'd appreciate any insight

Comment: I'm also going with your answers, becuase I feel that the first query, I understand the most!

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports window functions, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the "latest" record per group, and use that information to filter the dataset:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        s.keyid, 
        s.purchase_id, 
        s.status, 
        p.brand, 
        p.model, 
        p.keyid AS purkeyid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.keyid ORDER BY p.keyid DESC) rn
    FROM tStockMP AS s
    INNER JOIN tPurchases AS p ON p.purchase_id = s.purchase_id
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: How can I know if my database supports ROW_NUMBER. I have two dbs. The one I develop in (my personal laptop) and the one in the server where this query wlll be used.

Comment: @aarelovich: which database do you use: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: I've just checkd. RDS is configurued with MySQL 5.7. And apparently this is a feature since MySQL 8.0, so I don't think I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

First use `NOT EXISTS` in `tPurchases` to get only the rows with the max `keyid` and then join to `tStockMP`:

```
SELECT s.keyid, s.purchase_id, s.status, t.brand, t.model, t.keyid AS purkeyid 
FROM tStockMP AS s 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT p.* FROM tPurchases AS p
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tPurchases
    WHERE purchase_id = p.purchase_id AND keyid > p.keyid
  )
) AS t ON t.purchase_id = s.purchase_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ukDAusniSRbBSG7huAJwX/0).
Results:

```
| keyid | purchase_id | status | brand | model  | purkeyid |
| ----- | ----------- | ------ | ----- | ------ | -------- |
| 1     | 23          | 1      | HP    | NOTE1  | 6        |
| 2     | 23          | 1      | HP    | NOTE1  | 6        |
| 3     | 23          | 0      | HP    | NOTE1  | 6        |
| 4     | 45          | 0      | LG    | IPSLED | 5        |
| 5     | 56          | 1      | Bx    | BOX    | 4        |
| 6     | 56          | 1      | Bx    | BOX    | 4        |
| 7     | 56          | 0      | Bx    | BOX    | 4        |
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no doubt, it works and it is a valid answer. However the first option, from the previous question seems more straight forward, specially for a beginner like me. Regards!